# Volley Post Request for a file that is need password

Tags: android, android-volley

I set a password on my prefer directory on server with an username that anyone can not open and read that file. For opening and reading that file, web browser prompt a for that requests username and password. How i can set username and password in Volley Post Params?

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Method.POST,url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    pages = PageParser.parse(response);
                    adapter = new DailyReportAdapter(MenuDailyReport.this,
                            pages);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    pDialog.hide();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error.printStackTrace();
                    pDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(MenuDailyReport.this,
                            "Could not connect to server"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    finish();
                }
            })
    {

            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("username","mohammad" );
                params.put("password","mohammad123" );
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        ;
    };
```

Comment: do you use http basic authorization?

Comment: Yes i use http basic authorization

Comment: you should override getHeaders() and put authorization info into header, you may take a look on [it](https://yakivmospan.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/volley-authorization/)

Comment: i tested it with getHeaders() also but dose not work

Comment: @calvinfly I've used the code sample you provided. I think it partially works because instead of 401 error I now get blank page (answer). But if I remove password protection I get full page.

Answer (score -1):

Create your `HashMap` and return that from `getParams()`

```
 protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    Map params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("username", userName);
    params.put("password", password);
    return params;
 };
```

Comment: That is how it works in volley, there are plenty of tutorial available online. If it is not working for you only then you need to debug your code. Debug on server side, are you getting username and password?

Comment: see the example - http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: 401 means authentication failed check http://httpstatus.es/401. Either your credentials are wrong, or server is expecting some different key/value in post param or it require some more header param beside username/pwd.

Comment: I use this username and password in chrome browser and it work correctly. when i remove username and password in server every thing work correctly also

Comment: @Pr38y I think that authorization could failed because you don't provide correct headers with `getHeaders` override (you are missing it) and not necessary because "either your credentials are wrong, or server is expecting some different key/value in post param".